# IP adress for debian.org and debian.net

Tags: networking, debian, firewall, apt-get

we are enforcing a strict firewall policy at my firm and are whitelisting adresses on the internet.

My issue is this : 
I need to get a list of IPs (or at least a subnet)  for standard debian update packages (cdn.debian.net and security.debian.org) since my firewall won't enable DNS based rules.

Since debian.net and debian.org are high traffic websites, their IPs change from one request to another and I can't find a way to narrow the range.

When this is settled, I will need to determine which ports are used for apt-get, I would assume that http on port 80 is used, if wrong, please tell me and if able, point a resource about it.

Thanks in advance.

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main                                                
deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main                                            
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main                                          
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main                                      
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-updates main                                        
deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

I then opened my ruby console :

```
require 'socket'
100.times do
    p IPSocket::getaddress('debian.net')
end
```

getting 3 different results :

```
200.17.202.197
128.31.0.62
140.211.15.34
```

Same for debian.org, getting three results also.

```
140.211.15.34
5.153.231.4
200.17.202.197
```

Making me create at least 4 Output Rules on my firewall if I want my apt-get to be happy.
This brings the question of IP range I need to open, could it be that my test did not spot a used IP?
Is there any way to get sure of it?
Do these IP change at any given time?

Comment: Hi @floum, welcome to SU. We are much more likely to help you out if you can tell us what you've tried, do you have any ideas?

Comment: original post was edited. Hope that it clears things up.

Comment: A better way of approaching this is to force all HTTP/HTTPS traffic to use a squid proxy. You can then use domainnames / hostnames in squid ACLs to lock down access to the outside world. Otherwise you'll forever be editing IP addresses in your firewall config, trust me.